# "Warning: Unresponsive Script" when using Trigger.io Website

Tags: trigger.io

While using the trigger.io website, I keep getting "Warning: Unresponsive script errors" in Firefox every few seconds. The script is jquery, so I'm assuming there is some recurring ajax call causing the problem.

Is there anything I can do to stop this from happening? It's very frustrating and seriously slowing down the development process.

Also, is it better to click "Continue" or "Stop script" in cases like these? Both seem to freeze the browser most of the time.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the error]

Comment: The Trigger.io site and Toolkit is entirely unusable in firefox. Been like that for at least 10 months now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Chrome fixed the problem. Not a perfect solution, but at least it works. :)